# How to determine if an object inherits from an abstract generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types

I have a generic abstract class which I derive from:

```
abstract class SuperClass<T>
where T : SuperDataClass

abstract class SuperDataClass
```

The data type is limited to SuperDataClass, so every concrete data type must inherit from SuperDataClass.
In the end I have pairs of SuperClass and SuperDataClass inheriters, e.g.:

```
class DataClassA : SuperDataClass
class ClassA : SuperClass<DataClassA>

class DataClassB : SuperDataClass
class ClassB : SuperClass<DataClassB>
```

How can I check if an object, e.g. ClassA inherits from SuperClass without knowing the possible data type?

I tried the following, which does not work:

```
if (testObject.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SuperClass<SuperDataClass>))) {
    Console.WriteLine("The test object inherits from SuperClass");
}
```

So how does the if-statement needs to look like?

Comment: I am very curious of why you want to know this during run time. Could you elaborate on this to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: Try using *is* operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Comment: I have a methods which processes multiple types of objects. They all have one abstract class in common which in my example SuperClass<T> derives from. So I need would like to handle all objects which derive from SuperClass<T> during runtime in the same way. I don't want to have a separate handling for each concrete type if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively

```
Type type2 = type; // type is your type, like typeof(ClassA)

while (type2 != null)
{
    if (type2.IsGenericType && 
        type2.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(SuperClass<>))
    {
        // found
    }

    type2 = type2.BaseType;
}
```

Note that this won't work if you are looking for an interface!

Comment: But the inner type check is missing, must inherit from SuperDataClass as I understood the op.

Comment: @Matten His question: `ClassA inherits from SuperClass without knowing the possible data type?` where `ClassA` is `ClassA : SuperClass<something>`

Comment: type2 itself is not generic, it only derives from a generic class by using allways the same type (e.g. ClassA in my example).

Comment: @sqeez3r I do know this. But its base type is generic. "recursive" is the key word.

Comment: @xanatos: Sorry, I had some code of the other answers in my class which made my test fail. Your answer works very well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Type.IsSubclassOf%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) function in conjunction with the generic type:

```
if (@object.GetType().IsGenericType &&
    @object.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsSubclassOf(typeof(SuperClass<>))) {
    Console.WriteLine("The object inherits from SuperClass");
}
```

Where `@object` is the type you want to check (i copied the naming from your question, but object is no good name because it's the superclass of all classes).

If you want to check the generic type param as well, use

```
if (@object.GetType().IsGenericType &&  
    @object.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(SuperDataClass)) && 
    @object.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Superclass<>)))
```

EDIT: your last comment - non generic type deriving from generic type:

```
if (@object.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Superclass<>)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for generic classes. If the test object (Thanks for the hint, I changed the name) is of type ClassA<DataClassA> it only works with this statement:

if (@object.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(SuperClass<DataClassA>))) {
    Console.WriteLine("The test object inherits from SuperClass");
} The problem is, that I don't know the data type in advance either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @JonSkeet could explain this behaviour based on coercion/contraercion but I'm always mixing them up :)

Comment: Is it possible to notify a person that is not yet involved in this topic by using `@[Name of user]` ? Sorry for the off topic question.

Comment: @sqeez3r i think you need to check the class as well as the generic type argument, updated my answer.

Comment: @Matten: Thank you for updating your answer. The test object itself is not generic, it only derives from a generic class by using allways the same type (e.g. ClassA in my example).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently all obvious solutions (`IsSubclassOf`, `IsAssignableFrom`, `is`, `as`) do not work in this case. So I tried to force things a bit and came up with this way of testing if a class is `SuperClass<Something>`:

```
private bool IsSuperClassOfSomeKindOfSuperDataClass(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsGenericType)
        return false;

    var gtd = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

    if (gtd != typeof(SuperClass<>))
        return false;

    var genericParameter = type.GetGenericArguments().First();

    return genericParameter.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SuperDataClass));
}
```

Of course, this tests if a class *is* `SuperClass<Something>`, not if it *inherits from* `SuperClass<Something>`, so the next obvious step would be to write a function that tests all inheritance hierarchy for a suitable class:

```
private bool InheritsFromSuperClassOfSomeKindOfSuperDataClass(Type type)
{
    while (type != typeof(Object))
    {
        if (IsSuperClassOfSomeKindOfSuperDataClass(type))
            return true;

        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return false;
}
```

With these functions in place, the test you're looking for is:

```
if (InheritsFromSuperClassOfSomeKindOfSuperDataClass(@object.GetType())) 
    // do stuff...
```

Comment: This works as well. Thank you! Whereas your solution is more detailed and easy to understand, the solution of xanatos is more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Here you should have some clue as to what the expected type is. So in this case I would use the [Type.IsSubclassOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx).

An example of it's use is

```
Class1 myClass = new Class1();
DerivedC1 myDClass = new DerivedC1();
Type myClassType = myClass.GetType();
Type myDClassType = myDClass.GetType();

// Returns true.
bool isSubClass = myDClassType.IsSubclassOf(myClassType));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe because you answered in principal the same as Matten and you were second. I do not know. You answer seems valid as well.

Comment: It is utter garbage - I did not know about the above answer (which I have up-voted) until I posted...

Comment: I don't know why either. My comment on Matten's post should apply here as well.

Comment: Interesting why this does not work in your case. I will have a further look in a bit...